# Why do my answers cause me to have a question ban but not an answer ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

This is ridiculous. I finally got my question ban lifted for the 4th time, because of my beneficial Stack Overflow answers. Then, all of a sudden, someone asks an innocent question about localStorage [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26283339/can-html5-localstorage-stored-data-be-accessed-in-different-tab-of-a-browser/26283442?noredirect=1#comment41238810_26283442)

The Stack Overflow community starts complaining to this poster, assuming they didn't put any effort into finding the answer (without actually knowing), and I decided to answer his question. Maybe he/she doesn't know that you can access localStorage easily from the web console! I was there at one point.

So because I didn't treat them like a moron like everyone else was doing, I got downvoted to -5. After 2 downvotes, my question ban that had been lifted today was reinstated. Now it's -8 because people downvoted me for complaining about the downvotes.

If anything, I should be given an answer ban, not a **fifth** question ban!

This algorithm is not fair.

**Feature request**: if you're going to have an algorithm police the site, make the questions count towards the question ban and the answers count towards the answer ban!

Comment: What are you talking about? I see no question block on your SO user. Do you mean the ban _warning_?

Comment: So, conversely, good answers shouldn't lift your question ban?

Comment: I feel for you, but by your own admission, including answers into the algorithm made it possible to get unbanned..... so if they were ignored, you would never have been banned in the first place

Comment: From looking at the comments on that answer, it looks like people are downvoting because they think it's wrong, not because you "didn't treat [him] like a moron."

Comment: Fair warning: you're just begging for the meta effect by posting a link to your answer and using language like "This is ridiculous" and "This algorithm is bull."

Comment: @Oded you're right my ban was lifted again all of a sudden...but still it seems my four bans were mostly about my answers and not my questions

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, looking at the other meta posts from this user, it would not be the first time.

Comment: @gunr2171 I keep getting banned unbanned banned unbanned

Comment: Did you consider that the problem isn't with the algorithm?

Comment: this'll cheer you up:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=d5n_nMqH7CU#t=13

Comment: Nick, rather than complaining on Meta every single time you step a hair over the ban line, I highly recommend following my advice here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272601/feature-request-add-an-appeal-process-for-bans#comment100239_272601 and just getting those couple of bad questions dissociated from your account. That would end all of this, and there would be no need to keep arguing about this.

Comment: Hey...can someone tell me why my answer was wrong? Honest question

Comment: @Coffee even you? I thought we were friends

Comment: So is this a genuine feature request or just a thinly-veiled rant? If the former, I'd recommend adding the [tag:feature-request] tag and removing the inflammatory language.

Comment: Hey @NickManning remember when we talked the other day and I said I'd help? Read the message that you posted here: 'ridiculous', 'bull' and other adjectives in that vein are not going to help your case. Make sure you're adding proper tags (like Feature Request) and describe your request in clear terms. ***Most of all*** step back and count to ten before firing off a rant that will not earn you any favor.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reputation?s=t

Comment: I thought I did add the feature request tag...could it be that it was edited by a mod?

Comment: the question got deleted

Comment: @BradLarson I will do that...just haven't gotten around to it. But it's okay because my ban was actually lifted. Woo-hoo!

Comment: @NickManning [gunr2171 removed the tag.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/273157/revisions) You can roll back the edit if you really want to make a feature request, but be sure to remove anything that sounds like a rant and replace it with well-thought-out, logical reasoning for why your feature request should be implemented. "This algorithm is bull" doesn't count.

Comment: Hey...could the fact that the question got deleted be the reason my ban was lifted again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Think of it this way: You have a poor question track record. Your answers are irrelevant in determining that. Whatever algorithm determines your question quality will always say the same thing about your questions whether you have 1 or 1,000 answers.

Your overall answer score is, however, your *way out* of that block. Having lots of good answers with positive scores is what will lift the block. Think of it as a *separate* algorithm. So first, you check your question quality. Ok, that's not so great, block. Now let's look at answer quality, looking good? Ok, let's give him a chance to ask another question and improve that initial question quality check.

If your overall answer score keeps bouncing back and forth over the line, then naturally that "second chance" check is going to pass and fail depending on where it is at that time. The overall question score is remaining unchanged, though.

Comment: Got it...I think the algorithm can be improved by not causing an answer to cause a question ban to bounce back and forth over the line. Seems strange and unfair

Comment: @NickManning The bans are meant to slow down the posting of content that isn't working out well here. If there is consistency in posting badly-received questions *and* answers, why should there not be some cross-pollination between the systems?