# Does banning relatively new users encourage alternative accounts?

Tags: discussion, new-users, post-ban

**NOTE:** *This is not a duplicate of [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) I am not asking what to do once an account has been banned. I am asking about the effectiveness of the length of said ban on new accounts.*

Around the time that I had about 100 reputation (+/- 10 points), I was officially banned from asking questions.

Rightfully so! Now that I've spent almost a month spending time editing and answering questions in order to get my reputation up, I've learned a great deal about how to more appropriately ask questions. I've also learned a lot about how some of my previous questions could have been improved to avoid the ban in the first place.

Part of me is ashamed now that I understand where I went wrong; another part of me is understanding of the fact that I was a relatively new user (I've had my account for a while but haven't used it as aggressively as I have in the past 2 months) and that one must not only abide by the explicit *rules*, but the *implicit guidelines* of the community.

I'm not making a snide remark about the implicitness of guidelines! An analogy would be that it's not against the law to chew with your mouth open, but a child will learn in time that it's not acceptable within a proper society. I believe SO has quite a few rules similar to this to which I'm grateful for and understand with my increased time and experience on the site.

With that said, I respected my ban and have worked a bit hard over the past month to get my reputation up and keep my head down. I've gained about 240 points of reputation, which is where the point of this thread comes in:

> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines
> that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were
> poorly received.

240 reputation is not significant to a user with, say, 4000K rep. But when a relatively new and clearly inexperienced user who was banned at 100 points, is still banned at 340, it's rather discouraging. Heck, I'm even in the [top 4% for this month](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2016-04-01/5137782#5137782).

It's not that I had to gain 240 rep; it's that **I effectively tripled my reputation since my ban (+240%)** and am still considered to not have enough positive contributions to ask questions on the site.

Now, I doubt that a user who was banned at 1K has to earn at least 2.4K points. I don't know the algorithm and multiple posts have stated to stop trying; I get that. But my concern is that I highly suspect that many new users who made stupid mistakes, like myself,  in the beginning of their accounts' life and tried to earn their privileges back by editing, answering, etc. may find that the easier route, after no results, is to simply make a new account (which is against the rules). Or even worse, stop partaking in the site all together.

It's almost been a month since my ban and I have questions I would really love to ask, but I can't. Every time I get a new accepted edit, upvoted answer, or badge- I immediately check my privileges to be once again disheartened that I haven't earned that privilege back.

My aim of this post is to get some feedback onto whether the community feels that the aggressive ban on relatively new accounts encourages users to attempt to put out more positive contributions or results in new users making multiple accounts. I'm not arguing that banning a new user is justification for them breaking the rules by making an alternative account. *I'm arguing that when a relatively new user triples their reputation over less than a month and still has not had their ban lifted, then abiding by the rules and **doing the right thing** clearly is not being rewarded*. Might as well just go make an alternate account and leave the old one in the dust.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is not a duplicate. Please read my introduction. Thank you.

Comment: Well, there's no one going to disclose the exact algorithm how to unlift the ban from you. But the proposed dupe may give you some hints. One of the worst news might be that deleted questions count against you. And yes, it's often the case that banned users start out with completely fresh accounts. As long there's no interaction or voting frauds, that's considered OK.

Comment: No need for the introduction, IMO. It's pretty clear it's not a duplicate of that once you read it (it may be a duplicate of some other discussion, though.)

Comment: @8protons so, you were question banned, right? Then gained 240 points in ANSWERS? This is explained somehow that, even if getting rep on answers isn't a terrible thing to lift your ban (it definitely helps), it is VERY inefficient. Have you tried.... fixing your questions?

Comment: @Patrice Thank you for your inquiry and suggestion. Do edited questions get refreshed to the front of the page? In other words, if I go through the trouble of editing bad questions, how do I know that they won't remain stagnant and untouched? A lot of users don't even give a downvoted question a glance, so I don't see how editing a stale question is going to help me get the privilege back. If it does, I'll gladly try to fix my bad questions!

Comment: yes, they get bumped. which means, people get to re-evaluate it, which can be both good and bad. If you're going to fix it, make sure you're actually making it worthy of upvotes and not "just ok"

Comment: One aspect of fixing them is also to stop any further downvotes if they can be made to be in a more "well received" state.

Comment: Damn, thank you guys so much for the support and advice. I'm going to immediately start editing my old questions. What about ones that I deleted that count against me? Is there a way to revive those and edit them? Or should I leave those in the grave?

Comment: Question deletion isn't special in that it counts *more* against you.  It just makes it harder for you to surface and fix those questions.  Maybe a passing moderator would hook you up with a list of those, but that's a case-by-case basis sort of thing.

Comment: @Makoto no need for that - the OPs deleted questions are still within the 60  day window of being accessible if they click the "Deleted Recent Questions" option

Comment: @JonClements:  Oh, sweet.  That works.  This is one of those happy circumstances in which this is a more *recent* occurrence than others that I have seen.

Comment: I agree, being attentive does have its benefits @Makoto, this user is at least on top of their situation as opposed to just letting it go on without addressing it.

Comment: If you've got some questions (they could be deleted) that are not recoverable, there's a lovely "loophole" (not really, but it could be argued it is for these cases) in the user agreement that can help you... let's just say--remove those questions from your account.  Go read up on it.

Comment: Realistically, we just delete questions that aren't well-recieved if we get those requests, @will. Which doesn't really help here.

Comment: @8protons You should check periodically to see if the ban has been lifted. It's mysteriously tied into a number of things, including answer score. There's not going to be a message or anything, because eligibility is calculated on the fly.

Comment: I think the guideline is almost not practical for users who wants to leave question ban at all (at least under current rules and mechanisms), consider if fixing current questions does't help me to release ban, why do I still want to fix them?

Comment: I don't really post on meta, and I know we have to have rules, but can't someone just unban this guy? His post is better thought out and more articulate than 99% of users on this site, and its very clear that he's putting more effort than can reasonably be expected into getting unbanned.

Comment: Hey guys, I just wanted to say thank you for your support and encouragement. It sincerely means a lot to me and I can't thank you guys enough. I earned my privileges back yesterday; one user edited and improved a bad question of mine and several of you, I suspect, upvoted a few of my posts. In hindsight, I think one of the biggest things I've learned is to not take downvotes and flags personally. Ironically, I learned this lesson through interacting with new users who took my own downvotes/flags/suggestions personally, when I genuinely meant to only help. Anyways, thank you guys very much.

Comment: @nhouser9 Thank you so much for your compliment on my efforts; I got the ban lifted yesterday after some users here helped me with my posts (and upvoted some of them). This has been a great learning experience and to be honest, the support I've received from folks like yourself has been more than worth the effort to get the ban removed.

Comment: 4,000K Rep, I wish I had that! :)

Comment: "I've spent almost a month spending time editing and answering questions in order to get my reputation up" "I've learned a great deal about how to more appropriately ask questions" "I've learned...to not take downvotes and flags personally" I'd be willing to bet that you are literally one in a million here. Amazing attitude. If only all new users acted like this.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Being banned does make relatively new users more likely to create new accounts.**

It is a common theme and also the bane, if you will, of question bans. Some users when confronted with the question ban delete their account and get a new one, or just create another account entirely using a different authentication source.

I am not sure of the statistics, but I do feel like we need more users like yourself who are engaged enough with their current accounts to work through the ban process as opposed to bypassing it.

I have [written on this subject before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230857/178816), and at the time several changes were in the process of being implemented. Those changes included the warning when approaching the ban, and some sort of plan to make questions seem more like a resource that can be depleted. [The details are explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243460/178816) and good progress was made on throttling prior to the ban.

However, the aspect of dealing with users post ban I think still has room to improve. An aspect I had addressed which I think would also be relevant here doesn't seem to have been implemented - perhaps it is in the works or some aspect of it is, I just don't know.

> ### "question bans would be more effective as a throttle than as a cutoff"

Is the main point that I am trying to make here. While some users may constantly hit the ban by deleting their account and starting over, that would be much easier to facilitate if they were simply using the same account as opposed to a different one every time. Also, from a big data analysis perspective, having the same account allows for more pattern analysis than having them strewn about.

Furthermore, allowing some sort of throttle also gives these users some chance at an *attempt* for redemption. For example, once banned, if the throttle started at 1 question per week this user would have had the opportunity to redeem themselves after working hard for a week to learn the system. Throttles can be variable as well, meaning that if that 1 question again turns out to contribute to the ban the throttle increases to 1 question after two weeks. This process can go on while the user learns the system. The throttle should not be cumulative though, which is to say that after 4 weeks at 1 question per week, there is not a 4 question "credit", the account is still limited to 1 question per week until the ban is lifted.

Taking a throttle approach to the ban once imposed will allow users to retain interest in their accounts and be more careful with their contributions. Users who get into the habit of asking until banned only to delete their account is clearly problematic as it leads to more low quality questions, more moderation work from both the team and community, and a lack of investment from new users.

Comment: Users do get throttled under the current system. I'm not sure of the exact circumstances, but I think new accounts at locations with a history of bad questions tend to start with a 1-question-a-week throttle. It's my experience that many people react to this throttle by creating multiple accounts. I see regular cases where people create new accounts to exceed the cap on number of questions you can ask in a day or month. The truly desperate people who want folks to do their work for them won't be deterred by a throttle. That said, I think there is work being done on a throttle concept.

Comment: Also, people typically don't delete their old question-banned account, they just pick another throwaway email address and keep going with the new account. If the old account had enough reputation to upvote, they'll often use it as a sock puppet to vote for the new one in order to evade a question ban. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @BradLarson - The detection sounds like progress, and I do understand that some users will simply bypass whatever they can. However, the issue I am addressing here is kind of on the other side of the ban. As it stands now, unless I am incorrect, a question banned user who takes absolutely no action towards the ban metric will never be able to ask a question again. This is the side I was hoping to address with the throttle. Where, once banned, they at least have a narrow window in the throttle in order to ask a question if other efforts are not bearing fruit.

Comment: And that's what I hear is being addressed. I've heard multiple people at Stack Exchange acknowledge permanent blocks as a problem with the current scheme. Sounds like some amount of forgiveness over time is being worked in, and I thought this was already implemented to some degree.

Comment: @BradLarson - re: sock puppet. Some users truly do deserve a permanent ban. I suppose the hard part is determining how to strike the balance between that type of user, and someone like the OP of this post.

Comment: @BradLarson - I see where you are coming from, perhaps I should edit that aspect in to this post about existing throttle up front.

Comment: MY support for throttling instead of cutoff. The throttling could, however, ve progressive. But never cut-off

Comment: @BradLarson The throttle isn't entirely true IF the user gets banned overnight. That happened to me. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418672/i-received-a-question-ban-without-seeing-any-warnings)

Comment: @BlueRobin - It would appear that is by design, albeit poor design. The system assumed your location, device, or other identifying traits were indication of a bad actor and started you in the question ban process up front, bypassing any option to see a warning message, and leading to your untimely question ban.

Comment: @TravisJ How would it assume that?

Comment: @BlueRobin - Sometimes IP addresses are used by large groups (work settings, college settings, etc.) and there are sometimes bad actors in those large groups. That can trigger the system to label those addresses as bad actors and affect multiple other normal users.

Comment: @TravisJ I did log on from my school a bunch of times. Maybe that's why.

Answer (score 12):

This *probably* isn't a duplicate of the [oft-quoted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), but it's worth stressing some points.

> Now that I've spent almost a month spending time editing and answering questions in order to get my reputation up, I've learned a great deal about how to more appropriately ask questions. I've also learned a lot about how some of my previous questions could have been improved to avoid the ban in the first place.

Good!  Go apply that to your existing questions.  Fix them up.  They're the only thing that can undo the ban.

> Every time I get a new accepted edit, upvoted answer, or badge- I immediately check my privileges to be once again disheartened that I haven't earned that privilege back.

Those contributions aren't related to the *existing* questions you've asked; the ones that are actively counting against you in terms of the question ban.  You can have a thousand upvotes on *answers*, but that doesn't translate to questions or question quality.  I've seen users with rep in the 10K range ask poor, misguided, or off-topic questions before, and they were among the best answerers (top 15%, give or take) in their tags.

> *I'm arguing that when a relatively new user triples their reputation over less than a month and still has not had their ban lifted, then abiding by the rules and doing the right thing clearly is not being rewarded.*

Don't let anyone take away the fact that you're contributing positively here.  It's great that you're answering questions, editing content, and doing a lot of good stuff.

However, ***none*** of that relates to the quality of your previous questions.  In fact, the only thing you can do is to *fix* your previous questions before anything would happen to get you out of the question ban.

Comment: You sure the only way out is fixing questions? [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/273159/6083675) says differently.

Comment: *"Good! Go apply that to your existing questions. Fix them up. They're the only thing that can undo the ban."*  Is that something that the person under a ban has a way of knowing?  After all, the message is, apparently, *"The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh those questions which were poorly received."*  Good suggested edits and answers seem to fall into the "positive contributions" category.  If it's really just editing the same questions that got one banned in the first place, it should be much more clearly stated.

Answer (score 4):

As a user who is also question banned I am very pleased to see this kind of post being accepted well. The way you handle the situation of the question ban is the same exact way I look at it. You learn along the way and I want to climb myself out of this question ban. By learning/answering/flagging/editing everything I can do to make SO a better place.

As being stated over and over is that the exact strictness of the algorithm is not known. [Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273157/why-do-my-answers-cause-me-to-have-a-question-ban-but-not-an-answer-ban/273159#273159) Is stated that It is only a line between answers & questions?

So are the positive contributions(the rep gain?) you bring to SO included in getting out of this question ban or are only positive answers(upvoted/accepted) the way out of this ban?

I think there should be a proper explanation about this situation. I have a feeling this can be a motivation for starting users to exactly know what they have to achieve to remove the question ban and therefore lead to less dupe accounts.

Further regarding the situation I feel the ban is necessary to keep the quality high on SO. But it can be properly explained or tweaked to further make SO an even better place!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it encourages those who would just ask a question rather than invest time in searching for the answer to start over with a new account to ask their next question.

Personally I have found that usually the question has already been asked and I can find the answer by searching and reading the various Q&A relating to my question. However, this is not always the case. I have the experience (and currently still do) of having an answer ban imposed from cross-posting an answer due to my ignorance on some of the posting rules of SO.

I had a question, but found a half-dozen similar questions already asked (although none with answers), so didn't post my question. I then came up with a solution on my own and subsequently thought to post my answer. In my ignorance of the posting rules I posted my solution to the half-dozen or so similar questions. Of course, I was flagged and then a moderator deleted the duplicates. Result: I am banned from answering on SO (but not other stackexchange sites), and can't do anything at all about the moderator-deleted posts. And all I have been able to find about getting the ban lifted is that I must positively contribute, which can only be by asking questions since I can't answer and don't have enough rep to comment or interact in any other way.

I am not inclined to create a new account, and in my view it is not I who loses out by not being able to contribute answers but the other users who I may have otherwise been able to help if I was able to post my solutions to problems. I may not be a big help but I have since had 3 or 4 other problems that I have solved independently, for which the questions on SO are presumably still open. And for which I can't post my solutions, and even if/when the ban is lifted I don't remember what they were.

Apologies for drifting off-topic.

Comment: The system automatically detects if people post the same answer several times. This is to prevent spam, self-promotion and rep-farming. The only answer I see on your SO profile seems reasonable enough; I for one am willing to believe you acted in good faith. You could flag it for moderator attention, explain the situation and ask to have the ban lifted - IF the situation is really as you tell us here. (If you acted in bad faith, don't even bother, the mods can see your history!) Don't get your hopes up yet - you have to make a very convincing case to get a ban lifted.

Comment: Yeah, there were several questions that all asked apparently the same thing. I didn't know to just answer once and post references on the others. It's not (to me) an obvious course of action. So I got banned on my first and only answer. The FAQ says bans can't be lifted by mods. It is in some ways irksome but it is what it is.

Comment: The ban can't be lifted by mods? I'm sorry to hear that. IIRC you get a second chance after 6 months. At least that's how question bans work, not sure about answer bans. Your next answer would have to get upvoted, to get you on the good side of the banning algorithm. FWIW you seem an OK user, I hope you'll be able to contribute in the future. Best wishes!