# I received a question ban without seeing any warnings

Tags: bug, status-review, post-ban, notifications

Update: I am now unbanned! I finally did get that warning too. Thanks!

Update 2: Rebanned...

Update 3: I asked support for help, and they untied bad questions from my account! I'm unbanned now.

I recently got question banned (without knowing that such a ban even existed). While I understand the purpose of the question ban and why it is applied to my account, **I find it frustrating that I never received any warnings *before* receiving the ban.**

Wouldn't it be good to send users an email or some other type of warning as they get close to a question ban, but *before* the ban is imposed? I think this would have several key advantages:

1. The user can know that there is a punishment for bad questions
2. The user can know when they are on the path to a question ban
3. It would help the user if the user doesn't know how questions work on Stack Overflow

Even if only 10% of the people who are headed down the path to a question ban were to change their behavior, this would still be worth it.

**Update:** A moderator has informed me that users *are* supposed to receive "quality" warning messages from the system when attempting to post a question when they are close to the threshold of a question ban. However, I don't remember seeing any such messages, and a moderator has confirmed by checking my account history that I wasn't shown any. So, I think there is a bug here. I should have been given some type of warning before being banned. (And, no, my account is not blocked by SpamRam.)

Comment: The system is supposed to warn you when you ask questions while in danger of triggering a ban, though there have been reports from time to time of folks not getting the warnings.

Comment: @user4581301 I have gotten literally NOTHING about being question banned before being question banned

Comment: Important side note: Deleted questions are still taken into account when determining the ban, and I've heard rumblings that deleted questions count more severely, so you can't delete your way out.

Comment: Yeah, @user4581301. No turning back... Hopefully, I can somehow get out somehow. I posted TOO many STUPID questions. I dug myself a hole I can't get out of. I can't make a new account either.

Comment: Well, there is definitely something wrong here. As noted by @user4581301, you are *supposed* to be shown quality warnings when you attempt to post a question *before* you get to the point of being banned. I was fully prepared to post here a screenshot indicating that you had, in fact, been shown these warnings by the system, but imagine my surprise to see that you were not shown any such warnings. I don't know why not. It must be a system bug. That's not how the question ban is supposed to work, as far as I understand it.

Comment: @user4581301 Hopefully I'm not stupid and missed it while posting, but if that isn't the case then I should be free.

Comment: @CodyGray Was I shown the warning? I might have missed it somehow. I hope I didn't...

Comment: You were not shown any warning messages. Too many users are shown such messages and *do* miss them, which its own issue, but I can tell in your account history that you were never shown the warning. That makes this a bug, in my estimation. I've gone ahead and modified your question accordingly.

Comment: @CodyGray Ok, thanks. Wait, will my question ban be lifted?

Comment: I can't do that. No one can, actually. But that doesn't mean that there isn't a bug in here, or at least an opportunity for improvement. I see two possible scenarios. Either there's a bug that is preventing warnings from being displayed, *or* you were nowhere near close enough to the threshold to receive a warning but suddenly received enough downvotes to pass up the threshold to a ban. Even if it's the latter, I'm firmly in the camp that no one should be banned without *at least* getting one warning, so I would classify it as a system bug (or, again, at least an opportunity for improvement).

Comment: The bug/design-flaw relating to notifications/warnings aside, you are going to have to dig yourself out of the question ban in the normal way, documented in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583), by improving your existing questions. The bright side is that you have probably *just barely* tipped the threshold of the ban (which is why you didn't see any advance warnings), so you don't have very far to go in order to regain the privilege to ask questions. (Of course, you can lose the privilege again soon after regaining it, so you would need to be quality-minded.)

Comment: @CodyGray Ah crab cakes, I pretty much can't do that because of how bad the questions are... I tried editing all of them, but all of them are still pretty bad because they just can't be fixed.

Comment: Also, some backstory: I came back from a month-long break from stack overflow. I had a bug that I really needed help with. I come to submit a question, but it just wouldn't let me. @CodyGray

Comment: All you can do at this point is try to make some of your questions more attractive to upvoting by future visitors. I'd focus on the zero-scored questions as they're going to be easier to bring positive. Python's not my thing, so I can't really make good suggestions on what to improve. For the most part the way you structure the questions looks pretty good, but [questions like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71641018) might take too much site-specific knowledge to untangle. You probably hit the server too many times too quickly, I've done that more than once while debugging...

Comment: ... but for all we know you might have slept with the server admin's significant other. Sometimes you need to be patient with questions and poke around more at the problem site before asking at Stack Overflow. Maybe you'll have access again tomorrow. Maybe you need to throttle the rate at which your code accesses the site yourself to avoid getting cut off.

Comment: Re *"they just can't be fixed"*: As an *absolute minimum*, you can at least ***keep to form***. [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) and there isn't any need to address anyone in particular or call to action (that is implied by posting here). [Meta talk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) does not belong in posts (that is what comments are for). In particular, *"Any help would be appreciated, thanks."* is implied by posting here. Ask a real direct question instead.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Check the edit logs. I didn't really make that into my post kinda.

Comment: @CodyGray I am now unbanned! YAY! I did finally get that warning on the question post page.

Comment: Good that you're back, but be very careful with your next few questions. Pick and choose what you ask because if you don't ask a really good question soon you'll be right back at the ban. Research carefully to make it less likely that the question is trivial  or a duplicate. Take your time on the question, make sure you have [a solid example that exposes the problem with as little extra noise as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and hold off on posting for a while. Sometimes the solution will hit you in the middle of making a sandwich or a Doom break.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the FAQ on how to get out of a question ban - it's about why the OP didn't get a warning that they were about to be banned (which they [apparently didn't)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418672/i-received-a-question-ban-without-seeing-any-warnings#comment914790_418672).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine:  A year later and the bug hasn't been fixed?  While that wouldn't *exactly* surprise me, surely we're not talking about that situation in the second instance.

Comment: @Makoto Still, it really isn't a duplicate of the FAQ post on how to get out of a question ban (since the OP's not asking how to get unbanned, just why they weren't warned that they were about to be).

Comment: @Makoto The bug still isn't fixed?

Comment: It must be possible that someone asks multiple questions, no one votes on them so no warning is given when asking any of those questions. Then later the downvotes start to come in and goes over the ban threshold.  All the downvotes that lead to a ban came after their last question was asked.  This seems like a reasonable way that someone can get banned with no warning, and where the ban is still deserved.

Comment: I've just had a question ban, and I also haven't received any warnings. I was about to post the question because I am unsure where I could've seen/missed them, until I found this post

Comment: @idiot Yeah, It's pretty annoying. There's not a quick fix, and the mods can't really do anything. The system isn't even reputation based. Just try to edit as many questions as you can, and see if that helps.

Comment: @BlueRobin - Yes; The bug was fixed.

Comment: @stunlocked - You obviously have more than a handful of deleted questions.  The advice is the same, as the duplicate to this question, submit high quality questions once every 6 months. Moderators have the ability to confirm you the warning was displayed.

Comment: @SecurityHound I deleted them after I was banned. Not sure how it helps that moderators see that I didn't get the warning, since they can't help me anyway

Comment: @stunlocked - Deleting a question is never a solution.  By deleting your questions, you only made it harder to reach the required quality threshold, thus making the 6 month rate limit no longer necessary.  Since you deleted those questions, which must have been more than a handful (more than 5), since question bans are not a result of a couple (2-3) of poorly received questions.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't have more than 5 deleted questions, I have 4. In fact I was surprised because I don't recall deleting so many, and indeed, two of them were recently deleted by "Community Bot." - https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community. One of those isn't a bad or duplicate question so I have no idea why it was deleted. One was deleted by "Chris, Thierry Lathuille, Amit Joshi.". Turns out I only deleted one question myself, and regardless, I don't even have more than 5 deleted questions.

Comment: @stunlocked - 4 is still more than the vast majority of users ever have deleted in more than a decade of being involved in the community. Only one solution exists since you have so many deleted questions, ask a high quality question once every 6 months, and repeat that process until you are no longer rate limited.

Comment: This [has happened again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424142/208273).

Comment: @SecurityHound That's not entirely true. You can also contact support and they can untie questions to get you unbanned. However, you have to prove that you can contribute.

Comment: @BlueRobin - Disassociation of a question from a user profile is the exception not standard operating procedure.  In my experience my requests to disassociate questions from my own profile, that were serial downvoted, were not approved.  I have questions with 30 upvotes and 30 downvotes connected to one of my other community profile.  I routinely witness every single question in one of my other communities profile is downvoted, I can only assume, due to the fact I provided a comment that explained a downvote. I had to hide all my communities to avoid this behavior spreading to all my profiles.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'm confused. Are you being downvote targeted?

Comment: @BlueRobin - In the past I was. It’s the reason all my communities are hidden. Received dozens of downvotes from SO who happen to have enough reputation in another community.